# Preferred way to use sessions to avoid hitting the database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to optimise a Rails app with big load that currently hit the databsae on every request. I try now to optimise this by saving some info on the session so I don't need to go the database every time. I'm currently doing something like this.

```
def set_audience
  if current_user
    session[:audience] ||= current_user.audience
  else
    session[:audience] ||= 'general'
  end
end
```

And then calling `session[:audience]` anywhere on my controller and views. Seems fine except that I'm seeing on the New Relic logs that sometimes the session is not set and therefore the app get a nasty nil.

Im thinking better I should use instance variables, maybe more something like this.

```
def set_audience
  if current_user
    session[:audience] ||= current_user.audience
  end
  @audience = session[:audience]
  @audience = 'general' if @audience.empty?
end
```

And then calling `@audience` in my app.

Is this correct? I would like to make sure I'm used the preferred approach to this.

Comment: Where is this method defined and where are you calling this method?

Comment: Its a `before_filter` in the `ApplicationController`. Based on the audience value then the actions query different results on their index and show actions.

Comment: There are actually more: gender, age, location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard approach here would be to use a helper method on `ApplicationContoller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def current_audience
    @current_audience ||= current_user.audience
  end
  helper_method :current_audience
end
```

This will work pretty much exactly like the `current_user` helper method in your controllers and views. Depending on the specifics of your application, you may want to add some more robust nil handling, but this is the basic idea.